# Flyway: extra columns in the *_schema_version table

Tags: flyway

Is it possible to add extra columns in the *_schema_version table by using the Java API?

Comment: This question exhibits low quality. Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

No. This is an internal implementation detail of Flyway, not open for extension.

Comment: Is it than possible to set a value for the column 'installed_by'?